# Dynamically merge .env file old key value in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have to use file_put_content() function. But when the .env file $key value is empty then it will add new value other wise it show error. I need to merge old value.

```
private function setEnv($key, $value)
{
    $path = base_path('.env');

        if (file_exists($path)) {

            file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
                $key . '=' . env($key),
                $key . '=' . $value,
                file_get_contents($path)
            ));
        }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you please explain "But when the .env file $key value is empty then it will add new value other wise it show error. I need to merge old value." more, I dont fully understand what you are asking.

Comment: 1) => .env file i added key as "CLIENT_TOKEN=". Now the value is empty. So this time i run function automatically updated key. 2) =>Now  .env file key "CLIENT_TOKEN=sdsfsdfssdfsdfdhdghf" like. This time same function not working. @KurtFriars

Comment: No, I need to create new client token then merge with old one using same function. Do you have any idea? @KurtFriars

Comment: Yes, dd(env($key)) working fine. I cant replace old token. That's the problem for me. @KurtFriars

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218512/discussion-between-kurt-friars-and-gowsegan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you change the .env file, you need to refresh the Laravel configuration cache by `php artisan config:cache`.

So your function will become:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

private function setEnv($key, $value)
{
    $path = base_path('.env');

    if (file_exists($path)) {

        // Get all the lines from that file
        $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents($path));
        
        $settings = collect($lines)
            ->filter() // remove empty lines
            ->transform(function ($item) {
                return explode("=", $item, 2);
            }) // separate key and values
            ->pluck(1, 0); // keys to keys, values to values

        $settings[$key] = $value; // set the new value whether it exists or not

        $rebuilt = $settings->map(function ($value, $key) {
            return "$key=$value";
        })->implode("\n"); // rebuild the env file

        file_put_contents($path, $rebuilt); // put the new contents

        Artisan::call("config:cache"); // cache the added/modified parameter
    }
}
```

Comment: dont use `cache:clear` that has nothing to do with the config/route/view caching, it is literally your cache store that you would be flushing

Comment: Always thought that it empties the bootstrap folder :) But guess it clears the storage based cache. You are right.

Comment: it just clears the cache store, what ever you have that set as, so if it it was redis ...

Comment: @lagbox yes I forgot to remove the cache clear thing. You are absolutely right.